# attempt to reopen an already-closed object: sqlitequery

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite

So essentially I am querying the DB twice. I don't understand where this error is really coming from because I am not closing the DB anywhere. The code that returns the error runs like this. I've checked around and I just having seen a case like mine.

```
BeaconHandler pullAllDB = new BeaconHandler(this);
    try {
        List<Beacon> beaconsShown = pullAllDB.getAllBeacons();
        for (final Beacon bn : beaconsShown) {
            try {
                int messageCount = pullAllDB.getMessageCount();
                Log.d("Message", messageCount + " Messages Found");
                if (messageCount > 0) {
                    //Do Something
                } else {
                    // Do Nothing
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
                Log.e("Message", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

And the code doing the queries...

```
public int getBeaconsCount() {

    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BASIC_BEACON;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();

}

public int getMessageCount() {

    String mcountQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + MESSAGE_BEACON;
    SQLiteDatabase mdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mcursor = mdb.rawQuery(mcountQuery, null);
    mcursor.close();

    // return count
    return mcursor.getCount();

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should post a logcat if you are getting an error. It helps to see which line is causing your problem.

From the Android docs.

> close()
>
> Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making
>   it completely invalid.

Your call to `mcursor.getCount()` after you have closed it is likely causing the error

Maybe try something like this.

```
int count = mcursor.getCount();
mcursor.close();

// return count
return count ;
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't pick up on that myself. I guess sometimes you just need another set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that `pullAllDB` is your database object which contains the code doing the queries. In that case, before the line, `List<Beacon> beaconsShown = pullAllDB.getAllBeacons();`, you should do something like `pullAllDB.open();` and do `pullAllDB.close();` after you are done running queries.

So all in all, your function would look like..

```
try {
    //open the database class here
    pullAllDB.open();

    List<Beacon> beaconsShown = pullAllDB.getAllBeacons();
    for (final Beacon bn : beaconsShown) {
        try {
            int messageCount = pullAllDB.getMessageCount();
            Log.d("Message", messageCount + " Messages Found");
            if (messageCount > 0) {
                //Do Something
            } else {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
            Log.e("Message", e.getMessage());
        }

    //close the database here
    pullAllDB.close();
    }
}
```